# How to brush properly when there is only one geometric object in the GeometryGroup?

Tags: wpf, system.windows.media

I have a label (say, `myLabel`) with size 60x60 and I want to set its background by a `DrawingBrush`. My code:

```
GeometryGroup testGroup = new GeometryGroup();
testGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(20, 20, 10, 10)));
//testGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(40, 40, 10, 10)));
myLabel.Background=new DrawingBrush(
                   new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.Black, null, testGroup));
```

If I uncomment the 3rd line, it works perfectly (with two black squares within the label). But if the `testGroup` contains only one geometric object, `myLabel` will be entirely black. Either changing `FillRule` or giving the brush a non-null `Pen` does not affect the outcome.

So, how can I draw only one rectangle, as the background of the label? Thank you~

**UPDATE**: More source code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        GeometryGroup testGroup = new GeometryGroup();
        testGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(20, 20, 10, 10)));
        labelArray[i, j].Background =
            new DrawingBrush(
                new GeometryDrawing(
                    Brushes.Black, null, testGroup));
    }
}
```

will generate:

[image]

while

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        GeometryGroup testGroup = new GeometryGroup();
        testGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(20, 20, 10, 10)));
        testGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(40, 40, 10, 10)));
        labelArray[i, j].Background =
            new DrawingBrush(
                new GeometryDrawing(
                    Brushes.Black, null, testGroup));
    }
}
```

will generate:

[image]

What I want is there being only one black square in each `labelArray[i, j]`, which is also the original goal of the first snippet.

**UPDATE 2**: Thanks for @AngelWPF's suggestion:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        GeometryGroup testGroup = new GeometryGroup();
        testGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(-10, -10, 10, 10)));
        testGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(
            new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.Black, null, testGroup));
        brush.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        labelArray[i, j].Background = brush;
}
```

properly generates:

[image]

But

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        GeometryGroup testGroup = new GeometryGroup();
        testGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(20, 20, 10, 10)));
        DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(
            new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.Black, null, testGroup));
        brush.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        labelArray[i, j].Background = brush;
}
```

will generate:

[image]

where the rectangles are wrongly placed at the center of the label.

Comment: Can you please post images of how its appearing and how you intend it to be?

Comment: How do you want your 10 by 10 rectangle in each `label[i,j]`.... center aligned with black fill?

Comment: I thought that `new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(20, 20, 10, 10))` means "a rectangle with the top-left point at (20,20), width of 10 and height of 10" (seen from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rectanglegeometry.aspx#snippetGroup1)) so I don't have to align.

Comment: plz see my answer below and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your

```
   DrawingBrush.Stretch="None"
   DrawingBrush.ViewboxUnits="Absolute"
   DrawingBrush.Viewbox = new Rect(0,0,60,60);
```

Or use this XAML to apply to all labels...

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
       <Setter Property="Background">
          <Setter.Value>
             <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" ViewboxUnits="Absolute" >
                 <DrawingBrush.Viewbox>
                     <Rect X="0" Y="0" Height="60" Width="60"/>
                 </DrawingBrush.Viewbox>
                 <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                   <DrawingGroup>
                     <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
                       <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                         <RectangleGeometry>
                           <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                              <Rect X="20" Y="20" Width="10" Height="10"/>
                           </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                         </RectangleGeometry>
                       </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                     </GeometryDrawing>
                     <!--<GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
                       <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                         <RectangleGeometry>
                           <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                             <Rect X="40" Y="40" Width="10" Height="10"/>
                           </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                         </RectangleGeometry>
                       </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                     </GeometryDrawing>-->                                        
                 </DrawingGroup>
              </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
           </DrawingBrush> 
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Problems still occur when `GeometryGroup` has only one child: the rectangle will be centered, regardless the location specified.

Comment: Please see my edited answer below... key was to use `DrawingBrush.Viewbox`.

Comment: Yes, showing multiple rectangles is OK. Now I know if `Stretch` is not `None`, shapes will be stretched till the boundaries of the label. But I still don't understand why the behavior gets weird when there's only one rectangle.

Comment: And why arent you using the view box? I already specified that it gives absolute placement w.r.t. the X and Y specified. The rectangles shoul not be center aligned.

Comment: Oh I didn't know ViewBox before. Thank you @AngelWPF! And [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewbox.aspx) helps me too.